# get popup valus and send it to mail in android

Tags: android, email

i have an app which has a form values..

Title...
username...
email...
send(Button)
and this form is shown as popup window
my popup xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/compose_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#C0000000"
android:visibility="visible"
android:gravity="center"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#f47d7d"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20sp"
        android:paddingRight="60sp"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Popup"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/topicname"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Topic Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/topiccontent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Topic Headings" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/usermail"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter your mail" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

firstly,my popup window form is not editable..please suggest something to make it editable
secondly, i want to get these values(title,username and email) and send it to specified email address on send button click.
Thanks in advance

Comment: not editable means are you not  able to enter text ?

Comment: yes...it is not editable in popup ...but if i use same code of edittext in my main activity..it works....suggest something for my problm please @Haroon

Comment: Can you use dialog Fragment for the same ?

Comment: i have working code to acheive above can you ping me i will share it with you so that you can download and use the same harun.naik@yahoo.com

Comment: my popup edittext is working...now i just want to send email that having Title,username and email account values that user enters... on clicking send button in specified gmail account @Haroon

Comment: You have to use one library for that i will be posting with answer

Answer (score 0):

```
BackgroundMail.newBuilder(getActivity())
                    .withUsername("Your newly created Gmail account")
                    .withPassword("your password")
                    .withMailto(email.getText().toString())
                    .withSubject("TEST ANDROID STUDIO")
                    .withBody("ELOWWWWW")
                    .withOnSuccessCallback(new BackgroundMail.OnSuccessCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            //do some magic
                            Log.d(TAG,"MAI SENDED");
                        }
                    })
                    .withOnFailCallback(new BackgroundMail.OnFailCallback()     {
                        @Override
                        public void onFail() {
                            Log.d(TAG,"MAI FAILED");
                        }
                    })
                    .send();
```

Call the above method inside your send button clicklistner 
to import the library as module get it from this link https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground